# Waterbath canning chow chow

Tags: food-safety, food-science, canning

I waterbath canned some chow chow on Wednesday.  It was cabbage, cauliflower, red pepper, green peppers, and (was suppose to add green tomatoes and forgot)  can I open them, add tomatoes and can again? Today is Friday.
Thanks

Comment: My guess: you would need to bring the dish to a boil with the addition in it, and then follow sterilization requirements scrupulously.

Comment: The tomatoes would increase the acidity of the food, which effects preservation.